# Noise cancellation/reduction in iphone player

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to create an iphone app which reduce/cancel the background noise of the Audio ..Is there any existing library for this .? Is there any way to do this with AVAudioPlayer .?

Thanks in Advance .

Comment: Did you meant the Acoustic Echo Cancellation thing ?

Comment: I strongly feel this doesn't have anything to do with the player you use. Rather you should concentrate on **Audio Processing**. [This](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/AudioVideoStartingPoint_iOS/index.html) can be a starting point for you.

Comment: I want to play an audio file which have noise but users can listen to music without hearing any background noise.

Comment: Why would the audio files have (unwanted) noise in them? Recordings that have been made using the phone's microphone will already have gone through noise reduction during the recoding stage. Or are you expecting people to have LP / Music Cassette rips on their phones? The noise is far more likely to come from the surrounding environment where the listener is located than from the audio file he/she is listening to.